# Laravel update broke by composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I am trying to update from Laravel 5.0.35 to 5.1.0. I updated my composer.json file to reflect this, then ran composer update. During the update, symfony/security-core was removed.

```
- Removing symfony/security-core (v2.6.13)
```

However, it was never reinstalled. The update finished with an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface' not found in .../app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php on line 14
```

which was removed as part of removing that package. I don't see anything in the upgrade guide saying this should be removed or deprecated, or how to get around it. Has anyone else run into this? Or is there an easy fix that I'm not seeing? Admittedly I'm relatively new to composer.

Thanks!
-Eric

Comment: I'm going to throw in my 2cp. I've done some Laravel migrating in my time, and boy let me tell you; *you're in for a headache*. I would recommend just doing a fresh install of 5.3 (which is now the latest) and migrating your code over by doing a copy + pasta.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I Did that for going from 4.2 to 5.0, and after a lot of headaches, got it working. I'm not planning on going to 5.3, since 5.1 is supposedly slated for LTS, so I don't really want to go through that process again, if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the AuthServiceProvider in question was a custom built one that I had brought forward from an old version of laravel. I dropped the
    implements UserProviderInterface
and all seems to work ok now.